# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show whether:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

converges.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but explaining in your question the context (you found that exercise, solved it, and want to write the solution here for the sake of future readers, possibly asking for many different ways to tackle it) would definitely prevent some of the downvotes to come.

Comment: @ClementC. OK thanks for the feedback. Was just trying to do something positive, seeing that there are several similar (but not equivalent) questions like this on MSE. :/

Comment: That's a worthy endeavor. Just add a notice at the top of your question explaining what you intended to do: without it, your question is virtually indistinguishable from those of the form *"I got that homework, do it for me."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the ratio test:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{n^n}{n!} = \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \\
=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(\frac{1+n}{n}\right)^{-n} 
= 1 \div \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Taking the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$,

$$1 \div \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \rightarrow \frac{1}{e} <1$$

Thus the series converges.

Comment: Then why do you ask?

Comment: @KennyLau https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ :)

Comment: I don't see how this question benefits math.SE as a whole. It isn't like this question is hard, like the situation described in your linked blog.

Comment: Standard application of ratio test (AKA bookwork) should not appear as self-questions.

Answer (score 0):

**With a big hammer:**

By Sterling's approximation:
$$
n! \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$
from which
$$
\frac{n!}{n^n}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{e^n}
$$
and we can immediately conclude by comparison with the series (with positive terms) $\sum_n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{e^n}$.

*(Note that the "simple"-to-prove version of Sterling's suffices, the one with a constant $C>0$ instead of the actual value $\sqrt{2\pi}$.)*